# how to print all items inside dictionary if containing list

Tags: python, dictionary

I got stuck while printing the dictionary, any help will be appreciated..

```
cells = pdf.extract( [('cells', 'LTTextLineHorizontal:in_bbox("%s,%s,%s,%s")' % (x,y,x1,y1))])
```

Above dictionary, which fetching some data using co-ordinates, result is -

```
{'cells': [<LTTextLineHorizontal>]}
{'cells': [<LTTextLineHorizontal>]}
{'cells': [<LTTextLineHorizontal>]}
```

The problem is while I am parsing this data and try to print then all values are not getting printed. I am doing like as follow-

```
cells = pdf.extract( [('cells', 'LTTextLineHorizontal:in_bbox("%s,%s,%s,%s")' % (x,y,x1,y1))])
return [cell.text.encode('utf-8').strip() for cell in cells['cells']]
```

Calling the function and printing the value here, but all value inside the list is not getting printed-
it is printing only - 
`[b'SRN : U16571275']
[b'']
[b'']`

`print(SRN)
print(PMI)`

Comment: what does `pdf.extract` returns? a dictionary?

Comment: it's returning the data is encoded form `{'cells': [<LTTextLineHorizontal>]}`